# Type of data received from AngularJS POST?

Tags: json, spring-mvc

I send json Object from AngularJS POST

```
(json['name']="Name";json['lastName']="LastNAme");
```

In Spring mvc Controller I got this message

```
"name=Name&lastName=LastName"
```

I don't know the type of this message, whether it is JSON or String and how to parse to a java object.

Answer (score 0):

Create a model representating your JSON object.

```
public class Person{
   private String name;
   private String lastname;
   //...Setters + Getters + default constructor
}
```

Then in your controller handler :

```
@Controller
//Mapping here
public class YourController{

  @PostMapping
  public void getPerson(@RequestBody Person person){
    //process here
  }

}
```